# I can't initialize my project with Swagger2

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, swagger

It manages to initialize a basic hello world without the swagger, the error only came up now after trying to add Swagger2.

in all there are 38 errors

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-02-26T19:48:09.600-03:00 ERROR 10932 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiDocumentationScanner' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDocumentationScanner.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'apiListingScanner' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiListingScanner.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'apiDescriptionReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDescriptionReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'cachingOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/CachingOperationReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentationPlugins': Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginRegistry': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at com.allmichel.bookstoremanager.BookstoremanagerApplication.main(BookstoremanagerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiListingScanner' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiListingScanner.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'apiDescriptionReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDescriptionReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'cachingOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/CachingOperationReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentationPlugins': Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginRegistry': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiDescriptionReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDescriptionReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'cachingOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/CachingOperationReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentationPlugins': Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginRegistry': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cachingOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/CachingOperationReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentationPlugins': Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginRegistry': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/allan/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentationPlugins': Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginRegistry': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentationPlugins': Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginRegistry': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:127) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1397) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginRegistry': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:154) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:90) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1823) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1265) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 93 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/comparator/InvertibleComparator
    at org.springframework.plugin.core.OrderAwarePluginRegistry.<clinit>(OrderAwarePluginRegistry.java:45) ~[spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.plugin.core.support.PluginRegistryFactoryBean.getObject(PluginRegistryFactoryBean.java:36) ~[spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.plugin.core.support.PluginRegistryFactoryBean.getObject(PluginRegistryFactoryBean.java:28) ~[spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:148) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 102 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.comparator.InvertibleComparator
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 106 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm currently new to springboot, I don't have a good idea of what I can do. But before that I had switched to Swagger3, which also continued with errors. But I went back to Swagger2 because the project that was asked to be done was always done with Swagger2 by the company

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.allmichel</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookstoremanager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bookstoremanager</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Swagger UI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <description>bookstore manager project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.project-lombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Springfox hasn't been maintained for quite some time and is not compatible with the latest Spring Boot releases, not even the latest 2.x releases.

You can use [Springdoc](https://springdoc.org) instead. It's the current default library for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much, the courses that the company offered me are already a few old ones, other people in the company said that I was going to have some problems because of that. but you managed to help me thanks